# React sibling communicate and render

Tags: reactjs, render, siblings

In a react/redux application I have a container component that renders itself two child components: a header and a content part. My issue is that the header should render the title for the container. But this title is actually defined by the content part. The render method of the container looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='Container'>
            <ContainerHeader />
            <div className='ContainerContent'>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `renderContent` method renders different components based on the state of the container and each component defines the logic how the title of the container should look like. For example: A content that renders a specific item should place the name of the item in the container title.

So maybe I have a misconception here that causes this problem. My basic idea was that the container is structured into header and content so I make these two different components. But defining the title is dependent on the content and rendering the title is done in the header.

How can that be achieved? Maybe use React refs? Or do I have to change the hierarchy concept here?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably ways how you can achieve this with refs. However, I'd really recommend to take the cleaner approach and figure out the title before you render with `this.renderContent`.

So roughly something like this:

```
render() {
    const title = this.getTitle();
    return (
        <div className='Container'>
            <ContainerHeader title={title} />
            <div className='ContainerContent'>
                {this.renderContent(title)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is it possible in your case to extract the logic that decides which title should be rendered up a level into a function like `getTitle` as shown here?

Comment: Currently my implementation does it as u suggest. I have the title logic in the container and set it via props in the header component. But for encapsulation it would be nice to inject the title from the respective content component into the header. Without react I would set a getTitle() function on every content component interface. And would give this just to the header component. But that is not the react-way. The component lifecycle makes it difficult to interoperate between child components.

Comment: If it's really important to you that the getTitle Logic lives within a content component, you could put that logic in a static method of the content. That way you can call it from the owner class before an instance is created.

Comment: That is a good point but I cannot use static method because title is dependent on instance properties and I can't access this.props in a static method, can I?

Comment: You can't, but you can pass them as a parameter.

Something like `static getTitle(param1, param2) {…}` and then you can call it with `Component.getTitle(this.props.param1, this.props.param2)`.

Does that help for your use case?